# ¿Cómo puedeo hacer este JOIN?

Tags: codeigniter, join

Tengo 3 tablas, categorias, entradas y productos_entrada:

```
Entradas:
id_entrada | precio | fecha

Productos_entrada:
id_entrada | id_categoria | nombre_producto | precio_producto

Categorias:
id_categoria | nombre_categoria
```

Y quiero hacer que me queden los `resultados` así:

```
id_entrada | nombre_categoria | nombre_producto
```

Sé que puedo hacer un join entre entradas y productos_entrada y luego hacer un foreach y con `productos_entrada.id_categoria`, y sacar de la tabla categorías el nombre, pero eso me hace una consulta para cada producto.

¿Habría alguna forma de unir todo en un join?

Estoy usando codeigniter y la consulta no es así del todo, las tablas tienen mas campos, pero el problema lo tengo ahí.

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido a [es.so]. Puedes mostrar la consulta que has intentado y que no te está funcionando? Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas.Un saludo

Comment: El problema es que no sé como hacer la consulta XD. Yo sé que puedo hacer el join entre 2 o 3 tablas donde hay campos en común. Pero en este caso tengo hacer el join entre 3 tablas, la primera y la segunda tienen un campo comun por el que hacer el join (id_entrada) y la segunda y la tercera tienen en comun el campo (id_categoría) pero entre la primera y la ultima, no hay ningun campo que las relacione y por lo tanto tengo que unir la tabla "categorías" al resultado del join entre "entradas" y "productos_entrada". No se como generar esa consulta =(

Comment: Pues el primer paso es investigar :D  busca paginas sobre queries e intenta implementar lo que buscas.. cuando tengas algo, pregunta sobre un fallo concreto de tu consulta. Intentarlo es importante para aprender más a fondo que si te dieramos la solucion directamente. Animo y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta consulta, tenes la union de las 3 tablas.

```
select en.id_entrada, ca.nombre_categoria, pr.nombre_producto 
    from productos_entrada pr 
         inner join entradas en
      on pr.id_entrada = en.id_entrada
         left join categorias ca
      on ca.id_categoria = pr.id_categoria
```

Comment: @juan este material te puede interesar, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias Patrick! Yo pensaba que para que era necesario un campo comun a las 3 tablas para poder unirlas con un join! Ahora a revisar algunas partes de la aplicación que se pueden optimizar. Gracias!